# How Do I Enable SAML IdP in a Customer Community?

Tags: customer-community, single-sign-on, connected-apps, saml

Our Client need to setup an SSO for their customers from the Salesforce Customer Community portal into another web application using SAML. We are familiar with enabling Salesforce as an IdP for internal users, but not for Customers. Can someone tell us how to setup and configure a Salesforce Customer Community as a SAML IdP?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to enable communities as IDP, note it is very similar to the regular salesforce as IDP .

- Create a my domain for your organization. It is under the Domain Management in set up
- Under Security control find Identify Provider tab and click "Enable Identity Provider" for the org.
- Create a connected app with "Enable SAML" checkbox checked. Provide below parameters from your Service Provider

[image]

- Assign Profiles for connected app
- Download metadata for communities.Under SAML Login Information, click on Download Metadata.Note there will be section called "For Communities".
- The metadata has the certificate that you can share with your Service Provider

Comment: Thanks for this. @Mohith is there Salesforce documentation you used for this?

Comment: Try it out. Not sure I copied from docs, just went by myself and experimented